# (kotlin) Mockito helper to mock a method with a context

Tags: kotlin, mockito, kotlin-dsl, mockito-kotlin

I use mockito-kotlin, which is super great to do this kind of code, with `myMethod` being a suspend function:

```kotlin
mock(MyClass) {
  onBlocking { myMethod() }.doReturn("hi")
}
```

Now I'd like to use a context receiver in myMethod, like

```kotlin
context(MyContext)
suspend fun myMethod() {
 ...
}
```

The mock definition now doesn't compiler anymore because it expects a context, so I could do:

```kotlin
mock(MyClass) {
  onBlocking { 
    with(MyContext) {
      myMethod() 
    }
  }.doReturn("hi")
}
```

which works fine, but I have the same piece of code at 50 places, so I'd like to define a helper method that provided the context automatically. The best I could achieve is (this is mostly a copy-paste of the original `onBlocking` method):

```
fun <T : Any, R> KStubbing<T>.onBlockingContext(
    m: suspend context(MyContext) T.() -> R
): OngoingStubbing<R> {
    val context = any<MyContext>()
    return runBlocking {
        with(context) {
            Mockito.`when`(m(this@onBlockingContext.mock))
        }
    }
}
```

However at runtime I have the following error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class MyClass cannot be cast to class MyContext (MyClass and MyContext are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
```

Any idea how I could make it work - or another way to put the code in common?